# dropdown with form fields bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a dropdown that functions like in the image below (or go to [kayak's](http://www.kayak.com) website):

[image: Dropdown with incrementing/decrementing fields]

I need a dropdown field within the dropdown field, and then I need a couple of fields that allow incrementing/decrementing.

I couldn't even get a dropdown within the dropdown to work right. I tried variations of the following:

I've tried variations of:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <form>
    <div class="dropdown form-group clearfix">
                  <button class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Fare Class
                  <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                      <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Economy</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Business</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">First</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I didn't even know where to begin for the increment parts of each text field.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

UPDATE: I can't keep the main dropdown open to be able to click on the dropdown or increment/decrement field within the main dropdown. The main dropdown just closes on me. Below is my latest code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown form-group clearfix">
          <button class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Fare Class
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
              <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Economy</a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Business</a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class="mas10px"><a role="menuitem" href="#">First</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <h2>Bootstrap Counter Field</h2>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try data-toggle="dropdown" http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: Here's a counter field example: http://codeply.com/go/2VmBU7TanF

Comment: @Skelly Okay, I just tried the code (updated my question, last code snippet) and the problem is that when I try to click on the inside dropdown or the increment/decrement icons, the main dropdown closes out on me. I can't get it to stay open. Thoughts?

Comment: @JBear, interesting question! Have you been able to solve that problem?

Comment: @SPi Thank you and no, I haven't been able to resolve this issue - and I really need help taking care of this issue for a webapp I'm working on. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JBear Did you manage to resolve this issue?